# Implementing OCR in python for local language

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I need to implement OCR in python for one of the regional languages of my home town.

I searched around and read about Tesseract OCR Engine. But it supports limited languages.

How to go about modifying it to support other languages?

Comment: Did you try to just replace the dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

You could train Tesseract to support the language and characters of your choice, they have a howto guide here:
https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3